# Falcon M-37 possible glitch with firing?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

So i really enjoy using the Falcon M-37, I find myself using its semi-auto ability to its fullest. However this has caused the weapon to appear to be firing but the shell that is expelled does nothing almost as if it was a dud explosive. Is anyone able to explain this or perhaps as seen anything similar, or any future fixes for this weapon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same problem had happened to my in the multi. After digging some forum to find what was happening, it is [confirmed to be a bug](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/343/index/9772323/1#9783695).

So we'll have to wait for a patch until to use again this deadly weapon.

Comment: I've also been seeing this... funnily enough not in the first games I used it in (about a week ago), but in some games yesterday it did bug out a bit... though I found if I waited a bit longer between shots, it seemed to work a bit more reliably...
and it also seems to explode if there is a drone or the like in the way

Comment: I notice this bug a lot when I'm firing fast